# Date Filter in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have used two date controls to filter a row repeater as,

```
                oF_cell5 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell({id:"F05",colSpan : 2});
                var oCreateFrom = new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker("EV_AE_DATE1",
                        {width:"150px",placeholder:"Created From",

                            change:function(oEvent){
                                 oController.onChangeFilterValue(oEvent);}

                        })

                oF_cell51 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell({id:"F051",colSpan : 2});
                var oCreateTill = new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker("EV_AE_DATE2",
                        {width:"150px",placeholder:"Created Till",

                        change:function(oEvent){
                            oController.onChangeFilterValue(oEvent);}
                        });
```

Now i have a rowrepeater in which one of the column is CreatedOn date like..,,

```
                  new sap.m.HBox({
                   items:[new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"Created on:"}),
                          new sap.ui.commons.TextView("TV11")
                            .bindProperty("text",
                                    {
                                path: "CM_EventList>CREATEDON",
                                type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern:"MMM dd, yyyy",
                                    source : {pattern : "dd.MM.yyyy"}})
                       })]
                   }),
```

And in the controller i have written this code as....,,

```
                     onInit: function() {

    var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("eventlist.json");
    model.setData();
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(model,"CM_EventList");

                     },


                   onChangeCmFilterValue : function(oEvent){


     var CM_FDATEVAL = sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_AE_DATE1").getValue();
     var CM_TDATEVAL = sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_AE_DATE2").getValue();

     var CM_Date = new sap.ui.model.Filter('CM_EventList>CREATEDON',
             sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT,CM_FDATEVAL,CM_TDATEVAL);


     var oCM_VBOX1 = sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_CM_VBOX");
     var oCM_RR1 = sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_AE_ROWREPEATER");

     oCM_RR1.bindRows('CM_EventList>/eventlist',oCM_VBOX1,null,[CM_Date]);

     },
```

And the eventlist is my seperate json file which has date values as

```
                             {
                 "eventlist": [
                       {

                 "CREATEDON": "10.07.2014",
                        },
                       {

                 "CREATEDON": "10.08.2014",
                        },
                        .......
                         and so on..........
```

Now if select a date range from my date controls then the row repeater should show the records which are between the range of dates as in my json.

But the filter is not working.
Please Help me on this.

Thanks 
Sathish

Comment: please format code correctly

Comment: hi i have mentioned the code as in my view and in my controller ..... @Evgeniy

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use the [`DatePicker` Control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker) for date fields in your view if you aren't using it already.

You can obtain the value of your date picker as a Date object using the method [`GetDateValue()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/methods/getDateValue). You can then use these date objects to create a filter for a datetime field of your data model.

```
var dateFrom = this.getView().byId("filterDateFrom").getDateValue();
var dateTo = this.getView().byId("filterDateTo").getDateValue();

if (dateFrom != null && dateTo != null) {
    filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(
        "CM_EventList>CREATEDON", 
        sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT, 
        dateFrom,
        dateTo
    );
}
```

By the way: Note that both date objects will actually represent the moment at the beginning of the day (0:00:00) while the timestamps in your database will often be some point in time throughout the day. So when you want to search between two dates *inclusively*, you need to add one day to `dateTo`:

```
dateTo.setDate(dateTo.getDate() + 1);
```

Another problem you might or might not have to deal with are timezones... and of course [all the other falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the value of the following. The format should be different than your json value "CREATEDON": "10.08.2014".

```
 var CM_FDATEVAL = sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_AE_DATE1").getValue();
 var CM_TDATEVAL = sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_AE_DATE2").getValue();
```

Please try create a DatePicker with:

```
 type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern: ""yyyy-MM-dd""})
```

### Edit: to use Date as filter

```
var CM_FDATEVAL_DATE = new Date(sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_AE_DATE1").getValue());
 var CM_TDATEVAL_DATE = new Date(sap.ui.getCore().byId("EV_AE_DATE2").getValue());
```

Regards,
Allen

Comment: Hi Allen Thanks for replying. Ya i have tried with that code                  var oCreateTill = new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker("EV_AE_DATE2",
       {width:"150px",placeholder:"Created Till",
type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern:"dd.MM.yyyy"}),
change:function(oEvent){
        oController.onChangeCmFilterValue(oEvent);}
})                                                                      but when i select a date from the first date picker then its showing an error like this                                                          Wrong parameters defined for filter. -

Comment: Hi sathish, to compare date strings, it should be format "yyyy-MM-dd".i also found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765286/how-to-use-a-table-column-filter-with-formatted-columns. You can start to try with EQ to see if it works. then try BT.

Comment: Hi Allen,  Ya i have also tried that with only one filter property EQ, but the filter is not working.....

Comment: Your JSON date is a string "10.08.2014" whereas the datepicker expects a Javascript Date() object.
After loading the JSON file into your model, first convert the strings to proper date objects, and then follow the procedure as described in the link Allen provided

Comment: Hi Qualiture    Can u please help me on how to convert the strings into a date format...??

Comment: var d = new Date("2014-10-08")

Comment: Hi Allen i have tried the new edit , but its not working . when i debugged it is showing an error as                                       Thu Jul 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
__proto__: Invalid Date