# How to filter/sort OpenUI5 Grid by column, which is nested in the json?

Tags: filter, properties, nested, sapui5

I'm now testing the capabilities of [this grid](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html) and I'm having a look at [this example](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/Table.html#__2) at the moment.
Last week, I tried some basic loading of data, returned from the controller of the MVC app that I'm working on. It returns json, which I then give to the grid to be displayed.
The data, that I want to show, is stored in multiple tables. For now, I load data from only two of them for simplicity, because I'm only testing the capabilities of the grid - will it suit our needs.

The data, which arrives at the grid (in js), looks something like this:

```
{
    Cars: [
        {
            car_Number: '123',
            car_Color: 'red',
            car_Owner: Owner: {
                owner_ID: '234',
                owner_Name: 'John'
            },
            car_DateBought: '/Date(1450648800000)/'
        },
        {
            car_Number: '456',
            car_Color: 'yellow',
            car_Owner: Owner: {
                owner_ID: '345',
                owner_Name: 'Peter'
            },
            car_DateBought: '/Date(1450648800000)/'
        },
        {
            car_Number: '789',
            car_Color: 'green',
            car_Owner: Owner: {
                owner_ID: '567',
                owner_Name: 'Michael'
            },
            car_DateBought: '/Date(1450648800000)/'
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is some sample code of what I have done so far:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: BASE_HREF + 'OpenUI5/GetAllCars',
    success: function (result) {
        var dataForGrid = result['rows'];
        debugger;

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData(dataForGrid);

        var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
            selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Multi,
            selectionBehavior: sap.ui.table.SelectionBehavior.Row,
            visibleRowCountMode: sap.ui.table.VisibleRowCountMode.Auto,
            minAutoRowCount: 10,
            //visibleRowCount: 10,
            showNoData: false
        });

        // define the Table columns and the binding values
        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "ID of car"
            }),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({ text: "{car_Number}" }),
            sortProperty: "car_Number", // https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/Table.html#__2
            filterProperty: "car_Number"
        }));

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Color of car" }),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({ text: "{car_Color}" }),
            sortProperty: "car_Color",
            filterProperty: "car_Color"
        }));

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Car Owner ID" }),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
            // does not work like this -> text: "{Owner.owner_ID}"
                text: {
                    path: 'Owner',
                    formatter: function (owner) {
                        return owner !== null ? owner['owner_ID'] : '';
                    }
                }
            }),
            sortProperty: "Owner.owner_ID", // these two don't work
            filterProperty: "Owner.owner_ID"
        }));

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Car Owner Name" }),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
            // does not work like this -> text: "{Owner.owner_Name}"
                text: {
                    path: 'Owner',
                    formatter: function (owner) {
                        return owner !== null ? owner['Name'] : '';
                    }
                }
            }),
            sortProperty: "Owner.owner_Name", // these two don't work
            filterProperty: "Owner.owner_Name"
        }));

        var dateType = new sap.ui.model.type.Date({ // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765286/how-to-use-a-table-column-filter-with-formatted-columns
            pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy"
        });
        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Date bought" }),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                text: {
                    path: 'car_DateBought',
                    formatter: dateFormatterBG
                }
            }),
            sortProperty: "car_DateBought",
            filterProperty: "car_DateBought",
            filterType: dateType
        }));

        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindRows("/");
        oTable.placeAt("testTable", "only");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log("XHR:");
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Status:");
        console.log(status);
        console.log("ErrorThrown:");
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**My problems:**

1. I cannot sort or filter the list of cars by owner_ID or owner_Name. How should I do the filtering and sorting? Should it be done with the help of a formatter function in some way, or...?
2. I can sort by car_DateBought, but I cannot filter the cars by this field. First, I tried setting filterType: dateType, then I tried setting it to filterType: dateFormatterBG(it turns out, that dateType does exactly the same thing as my own dateFormatterBG does, btw).

   ```
   function dateFormatterBG(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
       var formatedDate = '';
       if ((cellvalue != undefined)) {
           var date = new Date(parseInt(cellvalue.substr(6)));
           var month = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1);
           var day = '' + date.getDate();
           var year = date.getFullYear();

           if (month.length < 2) {
               month = '0' + month;
           }
           if (day.length < 2) {
               day = '0' + day;
           }

           formatedDate = [day, month, year].join('-');
       }

       return formatedDate;
   }
   ```

Anyway, as I said, I tried both, but it doesn't work. When I click on the header of a column like in the example in the first link, I don't get any sort of a datepicker. How can I tell OpenUI5, that this column needs to be filtered by date and it should provide the user with a datepicker, when he/she clicks on the 'Filter' input field at the bottom of the dropdown menu? When I try to write the date in the filter field like '07-11-2016' (the way it is formatted), I get an empty table/grid. If I try to enter the huge number from field car_DateBought in the json object, all available rows in the table stay the same and when I reclick on the header, the filter field at the bottom of the dropdown menu appears with error-state.

Thank you in advance for your help and pieces of advice!

**Edit:**
This is just sample, dummy data. I try to load the real data and I see, that in the table I've got a couple of rows with date, which is today (07-11-2016, or 11/7/2016 if you prefer). That's why getting an empty table after trying to filter means it's not working correctly.

Comment: I am a seasoned developer climbing the same learning curve so please judge my input accordingly:: 1.Did you consider using an XML view declaration for your table? I ask because it would seem to be the more 'modern' way to go, and plus the declarative syntax is more 'human readable'; 2. Regarding date sorting, have you considered converting the JSON dates into javascript date format? I wonder if sorting might be simple in that format; 3: I have found the SAP Press Comprehensive SAPUI5 book to give good coverage of table sorting and filtering (worthwhile 60 bucks spent and PDF format too)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting: in a sample I am looking at the following appears in the controller:

```
    onInit : function () {
        this._IDSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("my_id", false);
    },
    ....
```

Then in the view there is a button defined in the header column as

```
        <Column>
            <Label text="Project"/>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://sort" press="onSortID" />
        </Column>
```

And back in the controller there is a further function:

```
    onSortID:  function(){
      this._IDSorter.bDescending = !this._IDSorter.bDescending;
      this.byId("table").getBinding("items").sort(this._IDSorter);
    },
```

I read this collectively as defining a sorter in the onInit(), then toggle/reversing it in the click event of the sort button in the column header via the onSortId() function. The [OpenUI5 API doc](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Sorter.html) re sorters indicates there are more parameters in the sorter constructor for initial sort direction and sorting function.

Following this pattern, for your needs to sort on the owner_ID or owner_Name, I assume you could set up a sorter as

```
this._OwnerIDSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("car_Owner/owner_ID", false);
this._OwnerNameSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("car_Owner/owner_Name", false);
```